# Why was this question sent to DIY?

Tags: discussion, migration

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/514793/revisions has absolutely nothing to do with home improvement and is blatantly off-topic. It should have never been migrated there.

Comment: You list only one incident. So, "stop sending your trash" seems a bit over done. I don't disagree with you on this single item.

Comment: @Marla it's not one incident, Voltage Spike has developed a bit of a habit at throwing questions which are off topic on EESE at other sites where they are even more off topic, this time it was home improvement, last time it was motor vehicles, etc.  The fundamental reality being missed is that many questions don't have a proper home anywhere in the SE system, because the system is designed only to handle the sorts of questions it can handle well.

Comment: @ChrisStratton. . . I understand, and this is an appropriate venue to discuss a problem. However, a title as strong as the one here needs further citations. I myself feel that the moderator Voltage Spike will learn with time. I would have voted to close had I seen the original question.

Comment: I am not sure what is the urgency to migrate or close a question. Perhaps a comment or answer regarding urgency to close or migrate might help.

Comment: this problem could easily have been addressed by EE.SE with guidance on handling the FWD/Rev pullup for direction sensing and pot setting with and a datasheet.  The power matching is a simple physics problem with f=ma with thrust power in water and boat mass and terminal velocity is also PWM average voltage or duty cycle.   EE’s must learn to translate any customer requirements into a valid Eng spec to solve easily. I see no reason for the rejection, other than lack of experience.

Answer (score 5):

I totally agree after looking at the situation, that question should not have been migrated.

I am wondering why a message was posted on our meta at all, typically a moderator simply checks the "reject" button, and there processes at SE run thier course, no hate mail needed.

The rejection rate is currently at 10%, if it became a problem I'm sure I would hear about it from a *moderator* at that site (the moderators are the ones that have to spend time cleaning up wrongly migrated posts), not from someone who occasionally uses that site. I would also expect that the message that they would send would be slightly more professional than "quit sending your trash"

Comment: "I totally agree after looking at the situation, that question should not have been migrated." The system says *you* performed the migration. Did you **not** "look at the situation" *before* performing the migration, or is the revision log not accurate?

Comment: Do you expect all humans to be perfect?