# Don't Migrate Garbage

Tags: discussion, migration

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/274991/220v-induction-heater-electrical-connection is NOT a Home Improvement question. It is not about hooking up a home heater - it appears to be about a device that belongs on a factory production line. Questions should not be migrated unless they are *absolutely*, *positively*, **100%** appropriate for the destination site as-is - not "this kinda looks like maybe it would fit over there".

If there is any doubt, DON'T.

Don't waste another site's time just because posted an off-topic question.

Comment: As @VoltageSpike [wrote almost 3 years ago](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7247/301846): _"if it became a problem I'm sure I would hear about it from a moderator at that site (the moderators are the ones that have to spend time cleaning up wrongly migrated posts), not from someone who occasionally uses that site."_ Don't you think it's up to the mods to sort these kinds of issues? You can always discuss this on your own meta, if you feel like your mods are too lenient.

Answer (score 9):

I'm the mod who migrated it.

> Questions should not be migrated unless they are absolutely, positively, 100% appropriate for the destination site as-is

I respectfully disagree. You cannot expect perfection. I'm not perfect and neither is anyone else, including you. The relevant point in the [migration flowchart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) says:

> > Is the question a good fit for the destination site?

It does not ask, is it "absolutely, positively, 100% appropriate for the destination site as-is". The flowchart allows for the fact that if it appears a "good fit" then that's enough. And in my, imperfect, view it did seem that way.

It's an electrical heater going onto a condo (according to the question) so my best-effort view was that it fitted as a home (condo) electrical question according to the DIY.SE [on-topic list](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which I checked before the migration. If you can explain *exactly* which part of the on-topic list that question doesn't fit, it would help.

So your complaint is noted, but not yet accepted. I'll discuss it with the mods on DIY.SE in due course, to see what they say.

Finally - your post here comes across as unnecessarily aggressive. Stop the attacking tone, please.